# Restart Certain Port of Tor

Tags: ubuntu, tor

I created one Tor config with a lot of ports.

I want just restart one Port for change its IP and I don't want to restart all Tor Ports, just certain Port

How I can just restart one port of Tor to change its IP? - for example Port 9055

OS:Ubuntu 16.04

This is a picture of Tor ports

Comment: ports are controlled by the process that creates them. a port is a program resource. If you want to restart it, you must either restart the process, or use an in-program feature to reload some part of the program. if there isn't such an option, and the process also created the ports you want to remain running, you may be out of luck.

Comment: There is a option Control Port.But I exactly don't know how can I restart one port.for example I can create Control Port 9555 and connect it but this control Port connect to which of SocksPorts? or if it connects to all of them how can I send a signal to one of them?

Comment: You are mistaken, Control Port is used to control tor server, it is used with telnet/ssh, e.g. telnet 127.0.0.1 9555 , then you can send commands to tor through telnet to control tor, be sure to create passwords if you enable control port, use authenticate PASSWORD to log in.

Comment: Yes I know that, also I created HASH PASSWORD and send signal for changing IP but it change all of ports IP.I just want to change IP one of them.For example I have 9050-9051-9052-9053-... and I want to change IP for Port 9052 but when I send signal it changes all Ports IP